# Extracting data from custom labelled dynamic tables in Azure Form Recognizer

Tags: azure-form-recognizer

I have a custom model with various labels and labelled dynamic tables. The model is labelled and trained successfully however when I come to my API to recognize the custom forms using that model. The labelled dynamic tables are not available for processing, I can see the automatically extracted tables in Pages -> Tables within the object returned.

However the labelled dynamic tables that I want to manipulate are unavailable and no data is returned.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

**API code unable to see value returned from the dynamic labelled table:**

[image: API code unable to see value returned from the dynamic labelled table]

**Form OCR Testing Tool labelled dynamic table:**

[image: Form OCR Testing Tool labelled dynamic table]

Answer (score 0):

Which API path are you using ? You should use the 2.1 release to get trained table information.